Spring Boot Application Not Reading Application.properties in Tomcat
I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application as a WAR into Tomcat. When I have things hard-coded, it works just fine, and there are no problems. But after my initial testing, I tried to clean things up and go back to the properties. And I'm finding that my application.properties file is not being read by the application during deployment in Tomcat. And I'm just confused.
My initial testing with Tomcat, to get the JNDI configured, was hard-coded, and everything worked just fine then:
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myJndiLocal");
    }
}

My context.xml is good and my tomcat's server.xml global resources are configured. The connection was made, and everything worked. Of course, hard-coded isn't what I want, so I switched to the properties.
Now, my problems are related to the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties. I have my properties configured in Application.properties, which is in my resources directory:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MY_DB?currentSchema=public
spring.datasource.username=postgresql_username
spring.datasource.password=postgresql_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.jndiName=jdbc/myJndiLocal

And I created a datasource configuration that prepares my database connection:
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {

        System.out.printf(" !!!!! Datasource Config !!!!! %n" +
            "   url: %s%n" +
            "   username: %s%n" +
            "   password: %s%n" +
            "   driver: %s%n" +
            "   jndi: %s%n" +
            "   jndi full: %s%n",
            dataSourceProperties.getUrl(), dataSourceProperties.getUsername(), dataSourceProperties.getPassword(),
            dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(), dataSourceProperties.getJndiName(),
            String.format("java:/comp/env/%s", dataSourceProperties.getJndiName())
        );

        if (dataSourceProperties.getJndiName() != null && !dataSourceProperties.getUrl().isBlank()) {
            try {
                return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(String.format("java:/comp/env/%s", dataSourceProperties.getJndiName()));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(" !!!!! JNDI Resource could not be found! Regular JDBC Configuration will be used instead. !!!!! ");
            }
        }

        DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        dataSourceBuilder.url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        dataSourceBuilder.username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        dataSourceBuilder.password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}

The first printf statement is just for current debugging, and I'll remove it later. My goal is to default to JNDI if present, otherwise use standard JDBC configuration. When running as a JAR with the embedded tomcat via my IDE, there are no problems. Properties are read into place, and everything gets configured as I expect.
 !!!!! Datasource Config !!!!! 
   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MY_DB?currentSchema=public
   username: postgresql_username
   password: postgresql_password
   driver: org.postgresql.Driver
   jndi: jdbc/myJndiLocal
   jndi full: java:/comp/env/jdbc/myJndiLocal
 !!!!! JNDI Resource could not be found! Regular JDBC Configuration will be used instead. !!!!! 

The problem now, however, is that my properties are all completely null when deployed as a WAR file into an external Tomcat.
 !!!!! Datasource Config !!!!!
   url: null
   username: null
   password: null
   driver: null
   jndi: null
   jndi full: java:/comp/env/null

I'm using the SpringBootServletInitializer for the WAR deployment, so I have to assume that is causing some kind of issue, but I'm at a loss presently as to what it is.
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.myapp.model", "com.mycompany.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.dao.jpa"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "com.mycompany.service",
    "com.mycompany.service.impl",
    "com.mycompany.myapp.webapp.pages",
    "com.mycompany.webapp.util",
    "com.mycompany.webapp.util.migration",
    "com.mycompany.myapp.annotations.validation",
    "com.mycompany.annotations"
})
public class MyAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyAppApplication.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I'm on the latest Spring Boot, 3.3.4, and am using the latest Tomcat, 10.1.31. I'm also utilizing Maven for the dependencies and builds. I have already confirmed that the Application.properties is inside the proper location in the WAR file - /WEB-INF/classes/Application.properties. Why are my properties not being read into the application, and what can I do to address this? I've been doing some reading and found this question, which is similar, but I'm not doing anything inside of my main method. DataSourceProperties is a default Spring class, so I would have expected it would just populate. The use of it as a parameter to my configuration method I would have expected to force a jumpstart even if it wasn't prepared automatically.

Found a resolution, although I don't really understand why it is needed, nor why it's helping. I needed to add the @PropertySource annotation to my DataSourceConfig. Once I did that, all my properties were in place, and everything loaded up perfectly, connecting to my defined JNDI.
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:Application.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    ....
}

So, the Application.properties clearly must already have been on the classpath in order for that annotation to work properly. I'm now mainly confused as to why it wasn't being used by the application? Is there something about Tomcat deployment or my current configuration that is forcing Spring to utilize its own internal defaults and ignore my configuration files? The documentation is telling me that the file should be picked up automatically.

Is your Application.properties a typo? The default name should be lowercase application.properties.

Really? That might be it. But I used the Spring IO Initializer and didn't change the default files and layout. Application.properties (with capitalization) was part of that. Then again, I might have had this one based on the Vaadin Initializer, since I'm also using Vaadin as my framework. Now that I think about it, I can't remember exactly which one I used for this instance.

Huh. Yeah, that was it. That was it exactly. I changed from Application.properties to application.properties, removed the @PropertySource, and it came up immediately. No issues, all properties present. Wow. Of course it was something that small. I need to dig around and figure out why it was capitalized. I know for a fact I used an initializer to get a packaged starter. Thanks! Please add another answer and I'll mark that!


Is your Application.properties a typo?

The default name should be lowercase application.properties.


In My First Answer, My Project.
If the file name of the configuration file is changed to ZZZApplication.properties ,
DemoJspApplication.java must be modified to:
ADD @PropertySource("classpath:ZZZApplication.properties") // Specifying a custom configuration file
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@PropertySource("classpath:ZZZApplication.properties") // Specifying a custom configuration file
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJspApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(">>> DemoJspApplication start");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJspApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(">>> DemoJspApplication after run");
    }

}

I've verified and tested it.

There's so much you can do, just using the default settings should be enough.

Spring Boot 3.3.4
Tomcat 10.1.31
JDK 17

Project Tree
demo-war-jsp-tag-db-Tomcat
├── pom.xml
├── Docker_MySQL
│   └── init.sql
├── Docker_PostgreSQL
│   └── init.sql
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── DemoJspApplication.java
        │           ├── ServletInitializer.java
        │           ├── HelloJDBCJSPController.java
        │           ├── HelloJSPController.java
        │           └── HelloController.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── application.properties
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            ├── index-tag-001.jsp
            ├── index-tag-002.jsp
            ├── index-tag-003.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── jsp
                    ├── show-hello-jdbc.jsp
                    └── hello.jsp

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-jsp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>hello</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Docker_MySQL / init.sql
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    age INT,
    grade VARCHAR(10),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    enrollment_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO STUDENTS (name, age, grade, email, enrollment_date)
VALUES
('MySQL Alice', 20, 'A', 'mysql.alice@example.com', '2023-01-15'),
('MySQL Bob', 22, 'B', 'mysql.bob@example.com', '2023-02-10'),
('MySQL Charlie', 21, 'A', 'mysql.charlie@example.com', '2023-03-12'),
('MySQL David', 23, 'C', 'mysql.david@example.com', '2023-04-08'),
('MySQL Eva', 20, 'B', 'mysql.eva@example.com', '2023-05-05');

Docker_PostgreSQL / init.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STUDENTS (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    age INT,
    grade VARCHAR(10),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    enrollment_date DATE
);

-- Insert sample data
INSERT INTO STUDENTS (name, age, grade, email, enrollment_date)
VALUES
('PostgreSQL Alice', 20, 'A', 'postgresql.alice@example.com', '2023-01-15'),
('PostgreSQL Bob', 22, 'B', 'postgresql.bob@example.com', '2023-02-10'),
('PostgreSQL Charlie', 21, 'A', 'postgresql.charlie@example.com', '2023-03-12'),
('PostgreSQL David', 23, 'C', 'postgresql.david@example.com', '2023-04-08'),
('PostgreSQL Eva', 20, 'B', 'postgresql.eva@example.com', '2023-05-05');

src / main / java / com / example / DemoJspApplication.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJspApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(">>> DemoJspApplication start");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJspApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(">>> DemoJspApplication after run");
    }

}

src / main / java / com / example / ServletInitializer.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public ServletInitializer() {
        System.out.println(">>> ServletInitializer() init");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.out.println(">>> SpringApplicationBuilder configure()");
        return application.sources(DemoJspApplication.class);
    }

}

src / main / java / com / example / HelloJDBCJSPController.java
Just use @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;
package com.example;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HelloJDBCJSPController {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloDS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getDataSource(Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("HelloJDBCJSPController >>>> dataSource = " + dataSource);
        
        //Put the DataSource in the model
        model.put("dataSource", dataSource);
        
        // /WEB-INF/jsp/show-hello-jdbc.jsp
        return new ModelAndView("show-hello-jdbc");
    }

    @GetMapping("/loadDataSource")
    public String loadDataSource(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Put the DataSource in the request
        request.setAttribute("dataSource", dataSource);

        // Forward to index-tag-003.jsp in the root directory
        return "forward:/index-tag-003.jsp";
    }

}

src / main / resources / application.properties
spring.application.name=hello-jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

# mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
spring.datasource.username=demouser
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# postgres
# spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb
# spring.datasource.username=demouser
# spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd!
# spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# jndi datasource
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource
# spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoMysqlDataSource

src / main / webapp / WEB-INF / jsp / show-hello-jdbc.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %>

<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Taglib 003 Example of sql tag</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:query dataSource="${requestScope.dataSource}" var="result">
    SELECT * FROM STUDENTS;
</sql:query>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.email}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>

src / main / webapp / index-tag-003.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.core" prefix="c" %>

<%-- Check if requestScope.dataSource is null --%>
<c:if test="${requestScope.dataSource == null}">
    <jsp:forward page="/loadDataSource" />
</c:if>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Taglib 003 Example of sql tag</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:query dataSource="${requestScope.dataSource}" var="result">
    SELECT * FROM STUDENTS;
</sql:query>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.email}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Please note that the content of this index-tag-003.jsp is very similar to show-hello-jdbc.jsp, except for a small section of content.
It contains the following paragraph:
<c:if test="${requestScope.dataSource == null}">
    <jsp:forward page="/loadDataSource" />
</c:if>

/loadDataSource => HelloJDBCJSPController.java
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource; // read it from application.properties
    
public String loadDataSource(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Put the DataSource in the request
        request.setAttribute("dataSource", dataSource);
        ....

Build
mvn clean package

Install and Config
Insatall war to Tomcat
copy target/hello.war
to Tomcat/webapps/
Config Tomcat JNDI Datasource
cd Tomcat/conf/
mkdir -p Catalina/localhost

create hello.xml
hello.xml
<!-- hello Context -->
<Context docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/examples" reloadable="true">
         
    <!-- JNDI resource configuration -->

    <!-- JNDI DataSource Configuration for PostgreSQL -->
    <!-- spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource -->
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWaitMillis="10000"
        username="demouser"
        password="Passw0rd!"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>

    <!-- JNDI DataSource Configuration for MySQL -->
    <!-- spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoMysqlDataSource -->
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/demoMysqlDataSource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWaitMillis="10000"
        username="demouser"
        password="Passw0rd!"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>

</Context>

Download Jar

MySQL JDBC Jar

mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.3.0/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar)
protobuf-java-3.25.1.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.25.1/protobuf-java-3.25.1.jar)



org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.7.4

PostgreSQL JDBC Jar

postgresql-42.7.4.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.7.4/postgresql-42.7.4.jar)
checker-qual-3.42.0.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.42.0/checker-qual-3.42.0.jar)



Copy Jar to Tomcat/lib

postgresql-42.7.4.jar
checker-qual-3.42.0.jar
mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar
protobuf-java-3.25.1.jar

Prepare Database and Start Database
PostgreSQL
cd Docker_PostgreSQL

docker run \
  --name my-postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=demouser \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Passw0rd! \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=demodb \
  -v $(pwd)/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -d \
  postgres

MySQL
cd Docker_MySQL

docker run \
    --name my-mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Passw0rd! \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb \
    -e MYSQL_USER=demouser \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=Passw0rd! \
    -v `pwd`/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql \
    -p 3306:3306 \
    -d \
    mysql

Test
Test 1 use default - jndi demoPostgresDataSource
start tomcat
cd Tomcat/bin
./startup.sh

Test URL

http://localhost:8080/hello/index-tag-003.jsp



http://localhost:8080/hello/helloDS


Note that it now displays the data content of PostgreSQL Database data.
check Tomcat/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
It use spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource
application.properties
# mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
spring.datasource.username=demouser
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# jndi datasource
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource

It should be noted that when spring.datasource.jndi-name is set, Spring Boot will use the jndi setting first, and then ignore spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username, spring.datasource.password, spring.datasource.driver-class-name settings.
Stop Tomcat now.
cd Tomcat/bin
./shutdown.sh

Test 2 use - spring.datasource.xxxx config

Delete hello.war

cd Tomcat/webapps
rm hello.war


Keep the Tomcat/webapps/hello directory.

Modify the contents of the Tomcat/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties file:


Set
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource
to comment and change it to
# spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource
Tomcat/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
spring.application.name=hello-jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

# mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
spring.datasource.username=demouser
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# postgres
# spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb
# spring.datasource.username=demouser
# spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd!
# spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# jndi datasource
# spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource
# spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoMysqlDataSource

start tomcat
cd Tomcat/bin
./startup.sh

Test URL

http://localhost:8080/hello/index-tag-003.jsp



http://localhost:8080/hello/helloDS


Note that it now displays the data content of MySQL Database data.
Note that spring.datasource.jndi-name (Postgres) is now used instead of spring.datasource.url (MySQL).
Tomcat/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
application.properties
# mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
spring.datasource.username=demouser
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/demoPostgresDataSource


I greatly appreciate the scope of this answer, and I'll upvote it because I can see it absolutely helping other people. But in my case, the problem was that the application.properties values were not being read into the application. So, the spring.datasource.xxx values you list were all null in my application when the Datasource was invoked. Even with an autoconfigure, the datasource was all null. That was the main problem. I've gotten around it by adding @PropertySource("classpath:Application.properties") to my DataSourceConfig, but it's not clear to me why that helps or is needed.

(1) I always provide a complete project content that can be copied, because this way, you can reproduce the results in your environment. (2) In order to avoid environment differences, I even provide the database settings ( 3) You can always say that the instructions I provided do not take effect in your project. The problem is that you did not provide the complete minimum reproducible project content. (4) If possible, you can provide a minimum project content. Put it in Your questions or may be posted on Github.
